# Why muslims have different ways for Wudhu (ablution)?

Tags: sharia, salat, history, prophets, wudu

I know about Quran verses and the different proofs everyone brings. My question is that, why Muslims have different ways of ablution and argue on that:

- **When the Prophet (sa) was amongst them for 23 years and everyone would exactly see and know how he made Wudhu !?**

And when did this difference come up, Mainly between Shia and Sunni I guess?

Comment: Note that the 23 years assumption is wrong, as prayer was not ordered with the beginning of revelation! And not everybody has seen him perform wudu' maybe he also taught people orally. So theoretically people may have got confused beside some differences already come from different interpretations of the qur'an!

Answer (score 2):

At first I want to say that, Allah says before praying you should do wudhu but he does not want to put you in hardship .as he says in Quran:

O you who believe, when you rise up to prayer, wash your faces and your hands as far as the elbows, and wipe your heads and your feet to the ankles. Qur'an, 5:6

All the Muslims had a same manner of performing Wudhu until the third khalif and it was the same manner of Shia, but he (third khalif ) in his middle years of Caliphate , was plagued by doubts when he compared his manner with the prophet . Then he changed the manner of performing wudhu to the way that is common in Sunny people and announced:

“Clean hands from fingertips to elbow” and insist on the “washing of the feet and not the anointed.

This heresy, opposed many of the companions of the Prophet ( pbuh ) , but the Umayyad because of their politic purposes Propound this manner in different parts of Islamic countries and made such atmosphere that no one could show his disagreement . So this manner was propagated.

Source:

Fars news agency

Comment: Since your source is not famous, please also provide a link!